# A good SSH client to open Gnome/KDE desktop sessions from Windows machines?

Tags: ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I'm using MobaXterm to open a Gnome desktop session on a remote system from my Windows 7 workstation with SSH and X11 forwarding. It all works very well, the remote machine is a calculation cluster that runs on CentOS. The only drawback is that MobaXterm doesn't seem to catch keyboard shortcuts like "alt+tab", which gets really annoying on the long run.

Is there another SSH client that would allow me to do what I'm doing now but with keyboard shortcut recognition?

Comment: Have you tried putty in combination with xming? I am not entirely sure if that would suit your needs though.

Comment: I haven't but I will. I'm confused though, some shortcuts work, like "shift+ctrl+n" to open a new terminal. So I'm thinking maybe the issue is not with MobaXterm...